# How to write empty strings for null dates via Jackson + Spring MVC?

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I tried using a custom serializer but it seems to never even go there when the value is null, so it never does my code to print empty string:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = NullDateSerializer.class)
    public Timestamp getFinalizedDate() {
        return finalizedDate;
    }
```

--

```
public class NullDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        if (value == null)
            jgen.writeString("");
        else
            jgen.writeNumber(value.getTime());
    }
}
```

So what do I do then?

I found several threads on writing nulls across the whole app using some ObjectMapper, and though I prefer to do it explicitly like using @JsonSerialize I tried that but it did not even work. I guess the old solutions dont work anymore. Regardless, I want to do it with a @JsonSerialize.

Using jackson 1.9.3 spring 3.2.2

Comment: P.S. I got a syntax error sorted out to get this solution to compile: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934045/null-values-as-empty-strings-when-using-responsebody-annotation But it doesnt work. Breakpoint in NullSerializer never hit, json for null dates come out "finalizedDate":null

Answer (score 0):

Isn't serialization for converting Object to String? The getter method you wrote seems to be returning a Timestamp (and not a String) ... probably that's why the serializer is not getting invoked.

Comment: It uses the getter to get a value to convert to a JSON string value. The serializer DOES get invoked, but never with a NULL value, even though there is a mix of actual dates and nulls. Jackson seems to avoid calling my serializer when the value is null so my if statement is futile.

Comment: If this is practice code, can you put the source code on github or some place similar? It might help to look at the source code in its entirety.